# Properties or Getters in JavaFX

Tags: performance, properties, javafx-8

Which is better to use: Properties or Getters?

For example:

1. getVal(){...} which checks for certain conditions in the object & returns a value

Or

2. make a public property, val; then use val.get()

I am inclined to use the second because I can bind to it, set listeners, wrap it in a ReadOnly view, etc.

My question is: do properties have any  (big) negative impact in terms of performance? Is it a bad coding habit to keep on the long term/use everywhere?should I use it with caution? Are there drawbacks or gatchas to watch out for?

Comment: the recommended pattern is to expose both getter and property: the former is for convenience, the latter needed for binding. To my knowledge the answers are no/no/no/no :-)

Comment: If you looked into the JavaFX framework itself. It also exposes both getters. And we use both of them. For example, getting the user entered text => textField.getText(), on the other hand bind the text to other property => label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());

Comment: If you want to observe (add listeners to) or bind to it, you should use a property. I would strongly advise against making the property public, though: make it private and use the [JavaFX property pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/properties-binding-tutorial/binding.htm#JFXBD107)

Comment: @James_D ahhh .. I see how my comment can be misunderstood :-)

Comment: Thanks all!  I kind of arrived at the same conclusion that James_D suggested. I made Properties either private or ReadOnly, then provided ways to set them.

Comment: @kleopatra Your comment is pretty clear and (as always) correct; however the OP said "make a public property", which is absolutely not the correct thing to do: I just wanted to clarify that.

Comment: @melkhaldi Your properties should be private even if they are `ReadOnlyProperty`s. See also http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/javafx-2-prog-model-1524061.pdf